# Instagram dark posts, using api to read info and do operations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api

my company is trying to make interactions with instagram dark posts(It is when you create an ad to target specific people, unpublished posts like facebook dark posts). I have searched nearly all of documentations and I am noting what I have found.

1. There is Marketing api in facebook [Marketing Api Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/ads_management/v2.6)
2. There is a link I have taken from a php **scraper** "www.instagram.com/p/{short_code}/?__a=1"

Option 2 is giving likes and comments but I think it is limited. There is another link with "/graphql?queryid=123123" that gives comments.

And another thing is I have not seen anything to post a comment to a dark post except Marketing Api.

My question is how can I do interactions with dark posts in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal `/comments` edge to retrieve comments from the post id. and POST to create comments on them.

It would work same as engagement on normal posts. Once you have the instagram dark posts with you.

One way to poll dark posts are:
`act_{pageId}/ads` would return all the ad groups. and you can filter only Insta post by checking weather `effective_instagram_story_id` exists in creative, and lookup the posts by id lookup via fetch object endpoint.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but what I understand is I am going to request ads from my facebook api and look for instagram story id, right? How can I differentiate dark posts then? Is there any criteria, variable or unpublished=true kinda tag there?

Comment: Not sure about the parameter in the API, you can try. My guess is that the at-least the flag should be present in the object lookup when fetching by id.

Comment: The problem is when I try to query media info from api.instagram.com it returns invalid mediaId but when I try to query it from scrapper links it returns media info. I think instagram standard api wont let people interact with ads. Do you have any info on this?

Comment: effective_instagram_story_id is not media id of instagram.

`graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{effective_instagram_story_id}` would return you the media object. This FB object lookup query.

Comment: That gives me application does not have permission for this action response. I think it goes to instagram business api which is not free. I tried to query instagram standard api with media short code from instagram_permalink_url but it returns invalid media id, or it has to have something with my instagram api token being in sandbox mode, i will try to publish my app to test it out