# Instagram ads engagement is only for business api?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-apps

I am doing a project for my company and I am stuck. I have to make [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/ad_creative) cost-effective.

In this link there are some methods to get comments and do comment but it gives me error: "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action" and when I try to query them with standard API it says that media_id is not valid(I got the media id with oembed code btw I am not putting there effective story id).

My question is:

Do I have any solution for getting and doing comments to ads other than switching to Business API? If I don't how should I progress with this? Should I just send my app to review with instagram_manage_comments?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad comments are on Ad media - and Instagram ads are only created via facebook ad account.

You have to use facebook ad graph API. You can check detail info at this answer: [Instagram dark posts, using api to read info and do operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172815/instagram-dark-posts-using-api-to-read-info-and-do-operations/47178431#47178431)

The link you gave in the question is correct starting point to fetch ad media and comments. However you don't need Instagram accounts to be converted to "business account" to be linked with FB page(more context for that [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/)). But you do need to connect with FB ad account for ads media.

Comment: I am creating an ad, I get the effective_story_id from the ad creative from api but when I query info with effective_story_id it says "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"

Comment: Yes, you need to submit application for instagram manage scope for review.

Comment: Even sandbox account doesnt have instagram permissions damn